# Command+Tab misbehaving for apps on multiple monitors

Tags: terminal, display, application-switcher

I tend to keep a few Terminal windows open in one monitor, and another Terminal window and Chrome open in another monitor.

When I'm using a single monitor, pressing ⌘⇥ remembers which Terminal window was last selected, but when some of the Terminal windows are on one monitor and some on another, ⌘⇥ away from Chrome always goes to the Terminal on the same monitor, not the Terminal on the other monitor, which is the Terminal window I last selected.

**TL;DR. Is there a setting I can tweak to get ⌘⇥ to work in multi-monitor mode as it does in single monitor mode, remembering the last selected window for each app?**

System:

- Terminal.app
- Chrome.app (latest official stable)

  <sup>(Though I could have listed any two apps.)</sup>
- Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is related to displays having separate spaces. This can be changed by unchecking System Preferences -> Mission Control -> Displays have separate Spaces. (requires logout+login)

Note that with this you'll get the old full screen with multiple monitors support (that isn't so nice usually)

Related also to other multi-monitor functionality things, see for example [cmd-tab behavior on Mavericks with multiple displays](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106405/cmd-tab-behavior-on-mavericks-with-multiple-displays).