# How do I stop the dock from moving to my second monitor?

Tags: macos, display, dock

I use an external monitor with my Macbook Pro, often to run Windows VMs with a task bar at the bottom.  While trying to use the task bar, I often accidentally summon the dock to the second monitor.  How do I stop the dock from moving?

Note: I'm aware of the option to go back to the old one-space-for-all-displays behaviour.  I don't want to go back to the old behaviour, I want to fix the new one.

Note, repeated: This isn't a duplicate of the question which asks [why this happens](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169719/why-does-my-dock-keep-moving-back-to-my-other-monitor).  I know *why* it happens, but there's nothing there that would help me to prevent it from happening.

Comment: You've made it clear this isn't what you're looking for, but for other people who come along, this link may be useful: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169719/why-does-my-dock-keep-moving-back-to-my-other-monitor

Comment: Agreed on both counts :-)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the other question.  That question is asking why the bad behaviour exists, and the answers say why.  There's nothing there about how to stop the bad behaviour.

Comment: Answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/665004/how-do-you-prevent-the-dock-from-switching-monitors-in-macos-catalina-or-big-sur

Comment: @JimFell thanks, but unfortunately not.  The answers there recommend reverting to the old behaviour; they don't say how to fix the new one.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent the Dock from moving from monitor to monitor in any version of OS X.