# show dock permanently on the primary display only or simultaneously on both displays

Tags: macos, dock

I have an external monitor connected to a Macbook. The current behaviour of the dock is that it jumps from one display to another whenever the cursor is at the bottom, which I find quite annoying.

Is is possible to change this to either of the following?

- Show the dock permanently on the primary display only
- Show the dock permanently on both displays

Comment: Similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239782/stop-dock-moving-between-monitors-while-moving-mouse-to-the-bottom-of-screen

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent the dock from moving:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 999 && killall Dock
```

This will keep the dock on your primary display, unless you keep your mouse at the bottom of another display for more than 999 seconds.

This works with separate spaces.

Based on the responses to [my post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253716507) on the apple forums.

Comment: While this seemed very promising i just tried typing that command in the terminal. It seems to have reseted my dock but it did not work; i still can move the dock to another screen by mouse placing the cursos at the bottom

Comment: I checked again by reducing the time to 1 second and back to 999 and it works as expected, my source was my post from the apple forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253716507 Did you really kill the Dock process? Have you tried rebooting? Tested on 13.0.1 (22A400).

Comment: Thanks for checking. Yes,  i tried first the command with 1 and i saw how the dock got hidden and then back. Then i tried placing the mouse in a different screen and it changes. Then i tried the command with 999 value and same behaviour. Tried on OS 13.0 Macbook pro M1 Max

Comment: I can now confirm that it does not work with all screens? With my Samsung LU28R554 (connected via displayport through a thunderbolt dock) it works, with a 4K Dell from work it does not - I tried DP and HDMI, nothing worked on the Dell...

Comment: did not work for me either..

Comment: Same for me on Sonoma, the Dock gets killed but when it comes back up it still switches between monitors nearly immediately when I move my cursor near the bottom of the screen. If it makes a difference, my external monitor is a bog standard LG (mumbles) 19 inch (it is identified as a M2280D in Displays) connected to HDMI via the dongle which came with my 2018 MacBook Pro (2,2 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7; graphics Radeon Pro 555X 4 GB
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB)

Comment: Also, for the record, it did not help to switch to a `root` prompt and enter the command from there, either.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the first, lock it to a single display - though it will entail a change in working practice.

System Prefs > Mission Control
Uncheck "Displays have separate Spaces"

Your Spaces/Desktops will then always move as a pair, locked together.

[image]

Then use System prefs > Displays > Arrangement
You can drag the menu bar representation to define your primary display. The Dock will remain always on this display.

[image]

As the Dock is always shown either on the active Space/Desktop in single-screen, or only on the primary display of a multi-screen setup, there's no way to make it appear on two displays simultaneously.

Comment: The problem with setting ""Displays have separate Spaces" is that it means I'll only have a menu bar on the primary display. For me, this is even more annoying than the dock jumping around.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Personally I hate 'displays have separate spaces' & have done since it was introduced. I've had dual monitors on Macs for about 20 years without ever needing that ;)

Comment: Presumably you've just learned to live with the Dock jumping around, or it never bothered you?

Comment: It doesn't go anywhere. It stays on my primary screen, right where I want it to be. It's separate spaces with mis-matched screen pairs, 2 menu bars & 2 docks that drive me bananas. I want one, right where I put it… muscle memory wins every time. I imagine if you use a track pad, it would be a long reach, but I never use a trackpad either. I'd call them 'the devil's work' but I don't think that adequately describes how bad I think they are ;)

Comment: does not work for me on Ventura 13.2

Comment: @Bersan - that really tells us absolutely nothing. What "does not work"?