# Can you have a dock on every display?

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, ventura

I have a macbook with 2 external monitors connected. I want to have my dock show up on each of the 3 displays. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Currently, it shows up on my built in display, with the caveat that that the dock seems to move to other monitors occasionally for unknown reasons.

I'm using Ventura 13.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one Dock, on one display [at a time].

If you use 'Displays have different Spaces' then it will move to your currently-active Space if you hit the bottom of that display with your cursor.
If not, then it will stay on your designated primary display.

[image]

Comment: Pushing the mouse against whichever edge the Dock is supposed to be on (usually the bottom) is what causes it to move to the desktop the mouse is on.

Comment: ah i see. I'm a bit confused by the name of this option though. what does "spaces" here mean? seems like a non-intuitive name unless i'm missing something

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some practical uses. @MarcWilson - interesting. Didn't know that. I never use 'separate Spaces' & of course without that it never moves at all.

Comment: I unchecked "Displays have separate spaces" and it still moves around. right now it's actually stuck on an external monitor and i can't figure out how to get it back besides unplugging and replugging the monitor cable

Comment: It shouldn't move without separate Spaces. You need to reboot to activate the change. One rebooted, then in Displays/Arrangement you can drag the menu bar to the display you wish to be primary. The Dock will follow the menu bar. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/369780/85275