# Immutable/Locked Dock Position

Tags: macos, dock

As discussed in [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/358567), as of Mojave, Apple has deprecated the ability to lock the dock to one specific screen/position, e.g. the key `position-immutable` is deprecated.

This question is asking for a hack/work-around to either (actually) lock the dock's position or (effectively) prevent the auto-dock-reposition based on scrolling the mouse.

It may be possible to accomplish this with [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/)?